# Allow a normal vlookup to work across multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a massive .csv file of approx 600,000 rows of different accounts, some of which have multiple contacts and email addresses for those contacts. The problem is that the email addresses for those different contacts do NOT appear on the same row in multiple columns for the same account but in separate rows. See EXAMPLE 1 in my extract.

I have tried using helper column and arrays but the .csv just crashes due to size of the file or even if I split the .csv into multiple files.

Formulas used for helper:
`=A2&COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`

Formula for arrays:
`=IFNA(VLOOKUP($E2&COLUMNS($F$1:F1),$B$2:$C$14,2,0),"")`

What I need to achieve is to get the data into the format in EXAMPLE 2 so I can just use a simple VLOOKUP. Is there a Macro that could help me achieve this please?[image]

Comment: Is it important is example 2 to clear the email rows and maintain the record of the duplicate contacts? You may be able to power query the table and then unpivot the columns for Email 1 by the contact, so each row of different emails is moved to a different column for the same row. If you need the empty rows for those contacts, this solution may not be suited for the problem. But seeing that it's the same email per contact code, this seems like a good fit and could eliminate the unnecessary rows.

Comment: Hi no I don’t need to keep the duplicate records. Just need 1 line per account with the multiple contact emails.

Comment: Not sure what is a Power Query? Is a Macro not easier?

Comment: Follow my answer and you'll see power query is simply a tool of querying data and doing systematic transformations on it. Very simple and relatively intuitive.

Comment: Ok so I think I have unpivoted it by the Contact Code column, see screen shot but I can't find the Advanced Options. See screenshot of my progress in your answer.

Comment: When the little window pops up for the unpivot, there's a little option there for the advanced options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Select your datasets and hit `Ctrl + T`, if you have headers select that option.

Then under the 'Data' tab of the ribbon, while you have your table selected select "from table/range". This will open the power query window showing you the table a little differently.

If you have 1 column with all the other emails, and the other columns are duplicates, remove those duplicate columns by right-clicking and remove. Select the email column and in the ribbon under the "Transform" tab unpivot it by the Contact Code column, under advanced options select "Don't aggregate", this will flip the column on it's side creating a new column for each of the email instances and if you removed the other column condense the table.